# How can I get a record created time from mysql in to img title section?

Tags: php, mysql, title

I building a video suggestion plugin [in here](http://neocsatblog.mblx.hu/addvideos/type.html).

This will be open when you press crtl+i (in this state only works with chrome).
Now, I would like to when the time icon (class name is "time_icon") is howered, display the created time for the post in to `<img title="">`, like in here:
i59.tinypic.com/259fy15.png
But I fully stacked.
I tryed this way, but the problem is this write out the varible name like "$datatime" and not the created time:

```
    <?php
    include 'config2.php';
    $connection;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `adatok` ORDER BY `id`  DESC  " ; //sql
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $datatime=$row['date_reg'];

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
    echo '<div class="video-header">';
if (!function_exists('echoOnce')) { 
$runOnce = false;

function echoOnce()

{

    global $runOnce;

    if(!$runOnce)

    {

        $runOnce = true;

        return "<img class='close2' src='/kep/icon_24x24_close_highlight.png'>";

    }

}

}

echo echoOnce();
$datatime=$row['date_reg'];
echo '<abbr class="timeago"></abbr>';
echo '<p>';
echo   $row['name'];
echo '</p>'; 
echo '<img title="$datatime" src="time.png" class="time_icon" >';
echo '</div>';
    }
    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

And the second problem is,if the variable name of "$datetime" working this write out all date time (I tested it in /date.php).
I can't use LIMIT atribute, becouse I don't whant get the same time always like:
2014.12.06
2014.12.06
2014.12.06
2014.12.06
Etc
 So the big question is:
**How can I retrieve an entry date in to the image title attribute?**
My table strukture looks like [this](http://i62.tinypic.com/akiq7b.png).

**Update:
The code is upgraded with this(thanks the answer for "Giedrius"!):**

```
$img =  '<img title="' . $datatime . '" src="time.png" class="time_icon" >';
```

And i included Jquery Ui tooltip.
Now only problem is the time not display always, but on there the source.
Try it in "Skyrim soundtrack".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use double quotes `"` if you want to print variable without concatenating it in PHP string.

In this case you can concatenate your variable with string:

```
$img =  '<img title="' . $datatime . '" src="time.png" class="time_icon" >';
```

Comment: Half working thanks!.
This very strange, but on the "skyrim sountrack" dosen't work.
I mean I see the time in to title atribut in source, but when I howered the icon I dosen't see anything.

Comment: If you want to use pop up on hover, you might want to have a look to jQuery tooltip plugins such as [qTip2](http://qtip2.com/demos)

Comment: Now I included jquery ui, and the problem is same.
I get the time all post expect "skyrim sountrack".